# What is the best practice for building an API that takes a long time to respond?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, asynchronous, request

I am building an API endpoint that has to call multiple external services/DBs and I do not want my users to have to wait for this process to take place, however, the result of this process is essential for my users.

My first thought is to add the request to a queue and return immediately, then at some later time, the user can query a different endpoint for the result.

Is there a better way to go about this? Should there be a webhook response instead of asking users to query the API twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three main ways I've seen:

1. Client sends the API request and immediately gets back a job number.  The client can then send a different API request with that job number every so often (every minute or so depending upon how long the usual result takes to get) so check on the progress.  On one of those checks the job will be done and the get the data.
2. Client makes a [webSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) or [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/) connection.  Client sends a request over that websocket/socket.io connection.  Server starts working on the result.  When the result is done, it is immediately sent over the webSocket/socket.io connection back to the client.  The client can then keep the websocket/socket.io connection connected for other requests or close the connection.
3. Use [Server-Sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events).  Send, the query and then when the result is done, the server can send it back on that same connection.

I don't think there's a "best practice" among these three as each have some advantages and some other uses which may be relevant.  The polling option #1 is the lowest common denominator and will work in any situation, but requires a polling strategy by the client and may have some latency (result ready before client polls).

The choices #2 and #3 are both very efficient and their general technology may have other uses also.

Comment: Good answer! However, can you add details as to how you may handle the page facing the user? Like populate default values on page load and as and when we get the details update them?

Comment: @LearningEveryday - That's your own user interface design choice.  You presumably show the user somewhere on the screen that the results are "in process".  Whether you do that in a glyph in the header that they can click on when the results and you allow them to do other things on your site while waiting or whether you take the whole page and just shown some animation indicating that it's still waiting is really up to you and how it fits into the context of your app.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Off topic, do you recommend any good books to learn more about this?

Comment: @LearningEveryday - I do not know of any books about this general concept.  There are multiple books on socket.io and on webSocket which you can find on Amazon with a simple search.  There's even one [here](https://www.amazon.com/Data-Push-Apps-HTML5-SSE-ebook/dp/B00J4YEIRE/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2) on server-sent events.